# How to prevent the textbox in react to cache/autoComplete previous values for any browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, browser

I am bulding a react application where i am using some textboxes to enter  some values ,but the problem i am facing is that the textbox is showing the previous values entered from the browser which i don't want. I  have tried using autoComplete="off" but it is not working. I am posting the code i am using for the application

```
<div className="myCSS">
<label>Store</label>
<InputNumber mode="decimal" userGrouping ={false}
value={searchCriterias.storeNumber}
id={store_number}
name={store_number} 
autoComplete="off" // Here i am trying to apply the autoComplete 
onChange={(e) =>{     
 modify(store_number,e.target.value);
}}
/>
```

Comment: what is InputNumber is it your custom component? from where did you imported it?